# How to properly cleanup this stack lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, garbage-collection

I'm working on a multi-threaded program, and one of the "apps" has the following code for a stack lock:

```
/*! Helper class.  Cannonical stack lock */
class StackLock {
public:
    StackLock()
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock_);
    }
    ~StackLock()
    {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock_);
    }
    static void Init();
private:
    static pthread_mutex_t lock_;
};
pthread_mutex_t StackLock::lock_;
void StackLock::Init()
{
    pthread_mutexattr_t mat;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&mat);
    //The type of lock set is recursive
    pthread_mutexattr_settype(&mat, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock_, &mat);
}


/*! Initialization. Called when the thread is restarted.
 * @returns 0;
 */
int32_t LibInit() {

    // .. other code
    StackLock::Init();
    return 0;
}

// There is no "cleanup" function.
```

Then the stack lock is used like this through the remainder of the module:

```
OtherObject* OtherClass::class_method() {
    OtherObject *object(nullptr);
    if (size() != 0) {
        StackLock s;
        // ...
        // There is no StackLock destructor
    }
    return object;
}
```

Our architecture allows for each thread to be restarted during runtime. I've notice that the pthread library allows for users to destroy mutex lock (with pthread_mutex_init), but there isn't any method to do so here.

So I have a few queustions:

1. Would the StackLock object destruct itself when it leaves `OtherClass::class_method()`?
2. Since there is no cleanup or call to `pthread_mutex_destroy` or `pthread_mutexattr_destroy`, restarting this module many times would run the risk of a memory leak. Right?
3. What is the correct way of destructing the stack lock and cleaning up the module in a safe way?

Again I apologize if these are mundane questions. The code has very few comments and is hard to read, so I'm having trouble following it. I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If at all possible, I'd switch to using `std::mutex` with `std::lock_guard` (or one of the other lock classes--`std::unique_lock` might be a better fit).

Comment: What does "restarting this module" and "cleanup up the module" mean?